# How to render data in react if object property value match certain criteria?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an array in react which has properties Name, Age and values-

```
[{Name:'Martha', Age: 15},{Name:'Candice', Age: 19},{Name:'Ruby', Age: 7}]
```

I need to display the names based on age i.e. if Age >18, they should be grouped under Adult heading, else kids. How can I do that?

This is what is expected-

```
ADULT
Candice

KIDS
Martha
Ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

This is inefficient but would work. Basically, filter the array for adults and kids then render the list.

```
const TestComponent = () => {
  const userList = [{Name:'Martha', Age: 15},{Name:'Candice', Age: 19},{Name:'Ruby', Age: 7}];
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Adult</span>
      <ul>
        {userList
          .filter((user) => user.Age >= 18)
          .map((user) => (
            <li>{user.Name}</li>
          ))}
      </ul>

      <span>Kids</span>
      <ul>
        {userList
          .filter((user) => user.Age < 18)
          .map((user) => (
            <li>{user.Name}</li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```